# How can i chain one method dynamically in jquery?

Tags: jquery

`enter code here`Hey guys my question is basically a scenario. Consider a `page.php` which sends numeric data via POST or GET to `page2.php`.

What I want to do is based on that number from `page.php` (for example, `5`) I want to create a chain of the same method call to a jQuery object like this:

```
jquery("any").a().a().a().a().a();
```

Is there any way to do that?
here is the sample code and i want to chain multiple times the cluster method to be chained with the map object

```
   $('.map')
      .gmap3({
        center: [46.578498,2.457275],
        zoom: 4
      })
      .cluster({
        size: 200,
        markers: [
          {position: [48.8620722, 2.352047]},
          {position: [44.28952958093682, 6.152559438984804]},
          {position: [49.28952958093682, -1.1501188139848408]},
          {position: [44.28952958093682, -1.1501188139848408]}
        ],
        cb: function (markers) {
          if (markers.length > 1) { // 1 marker stay unchanged (because cb returns nothing)
            if (markers.length < 20) {
              return {
                content: "<div class='cluster cluster-1'>" + markers.length + "</div>",
                x: -26,
                y: -26
              };
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { $('.any').a(); });` Alternatively if you have control of the method you're calling, change it to accept a parameter which is the number of times it should perform its operation and just call it once

Comment: Is it not, more like this? $('.any') = $('.any').a(), otherwise you don't do .a().a().a(), but only each time $('.any').a()

Comment: gmap3.net/api-cluster.html please check this url where u can see a sample code the method i want to chain multiple time is the cluster method

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple for loop

```js
var $ele = jquery("any");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  $ele = $ele['a']();
  // or
  //  $ele = $ele.a();
```

Comment: http://gmap3.net/api-cluster.html   please check this url where u can see a sample code the method i want to chain multiple time is the cluster method

Comment: Please share your code and o/p that you getting . Depending on what function you wanna call repeatedly solution can be provided.

Comment: @user36605 : for multiple cluster, may the object param differ?

Comment: yeah for each cluster method the object parameter can be different

Comment: @user36605 : store it in array and pass

Comment: how can i add multiple cluster method dynamically suppose by using a loop or any thing else which can help me